# How to map strings/poor JSON to C# object members? (and ultimately to a MySQL database)

Tags: c#, mysql, json, linq

(This is all kind of background to give you context around my problem. You can skip down to "The Problem" and read that, and then maybe come back up and skim the background if you want to get straight to the point. Sorry it's a wall of text!)

---

I've got a bunch of terrible, terrible JSON I need to store in a database. Essentially, someone took a large XML file, and serialized it to one, big, flat JSON object by simply using the XML's XPath. Here's an example of what I mean:

**Original XML:**

```
<statistics>
    <sample>
        <date>2012-5-10</date>
        <duration>11.2</duration>
    </sample>
    <sample>
        <date>2012-6-10</date>
        <duration>13.1</duration>
    </sample>
    <sample>
        <date>2012-7-10</date>
        <duration>10.0</duration>
    </sample>
</statistics>
```

---

**The Horrible JSON I Have to Work With:** (basically just the XPath from above)

```
{
    "statistics":"",

    "statistics/sample":"",
    "statistics/sample/date":"2012-5-10",
    "statistics/sample/duration":"11.2",

    "statistics/sample@1":"",
    "statistics/sample/date@1":"2012-6-10",
    "statistics/sample/duration@1":"13.1",

    "statistics/sample@2":"",
    "statistics/sample/date@2":"2012-7-10",
    "statistics/sample/duration@2":"10.0",
}
```

And now I need to put it in a database that contains a `statistics` table with `date` and `duration` columns.

**How I'm Currently Doing It:** (or at least a simple example of how)

```
Tuple<string, string>[] jsonToColumn = // maps JSON value to SQL table column
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("statistics/sample/date", "date"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("statistics/sample/duration", "duration")
};

// Parse the JSON text
// jsonText is just a string holding the raw JSON
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> json = serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonText) as Dictionary<string, object>;

// Duplicate JSON fields have some "@\d+" string appended to them, so we can
// find these and use them to help uniquely identify each individual sample.
List<string> sampleIndices = new List<string>();
foreach (string k in json.Keys)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(k, "^statistics/sample(@\\d*)?$");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        sampleIndices .Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}

// And now take each "index" (of the form "@\d+" (or "" for the first item))
// and generate a SQL query for its sample.
foreach (string index in compressionIndices)
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    List<string> columns = new List<string>();
    foreach (Tuple<string, string> t in jsonToColumn)
    {
        object result;
        if (json.TryGetValue(t.Item1 + index, out result))
        {
            columns.Add(t.Item2);
            values.Add(result);
        }
    }

    string statement = "INSERT INTO statistics(" + string.Join(", ", columns) + ") VALUES(" + string.Join(", ", values) + ");";
    // And execute the statement...
}
```

However, I'd like to use an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (or something LINQ-ish) rather than this hackery, because I need to start performing some queries before inserting and apply some updates, and creating and executing my own SQL statements is just... cumbersome. I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (.edmx) file and set things up, and now I can easily use this model to interact with and write to my database.

---

**The Problem/Question**

The problem is I'm not sure how to best map from my JSON to my ADO.NET Entity Data Model `Statistic` object (that represents a sample/record in the `statistics` table). The easiest would be to change my `Tuple` list to use something like pointers-to-members (a la `Tuple<string, Statistic::*Duration>("statistics/sample/duration", &Statistic::Duration)` if this were C++), but a) I don't even think this is possible in C#, and b) even if it was it makes my `Tuple`s all have different types.

What are some of my options here? How can I best map the JSON to my `Statistic` objects? I'm kinda new to the LINQ world, and am wondering if there's a way (through LINQ or something else) to map these values.

It's a sub-optimal position I'm in (working with such poor JSON), and I recognize it's possible that maybe my current method is better than anything else given my situation, and if that's the case I'd even accept that as my answer. But I would really like to explore what options there are for mapping this JSON to a C# object (and ultimately to the SQL database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole problem is mapping that "JSON" you have to POCO entities, here's an example on how to Deserialize it using a Custom `JavascriptConverter`:

Your POCO entities:

```
public class Statistics
{
    public Statistics()
    {
        Samples = new List<Sample>();
    }

    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public float Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Your StatsConverter:

```
public class StatsConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        else if (type == typeof(Statistics))
        {
            Statistics statistics = null;
            Sample sample = null;
            {
                foreach (var item in dictionary.Keys)
                {
                    if (dictionary[item] is string && item.Contains("duration"))
                        sample.Duration = float.Parse(dictionary[item].ToString());
                    else if (dictionary[item] is string && item.Contains("date"))
                        sample.Date = DateTime.Parse((dictionary[item].ToString()));
                    else if (dictionary[item] is string && item.Contains("sample"))
                    {
                        sample = new Sample();
                        statistics.Samples.Add(sample);
                    }
                    else if (dictionary[item] is string && item.Contains("statistics"))
                        statistics = new Statistics();
                }
            }
            return statistics;
        }
        return null;
    }    

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new Type[] { typeof(Statistics)})); }
    }
}
```

Now a sample on how to Deserialize it:

```
string json = @"{
""statistics"":"""",

""statistics/sample"":"""",
""statistics/sample/date"":""2012-5-10"",
""statistics/sample/duration"":""11.2"",

""statistics/sample@1"":"""",
""statistics/sample/date@1"":""2012-6-10"",
""statistics/sample/duration@1"":""13.1"",

""statistics/sample@2"":"""",
""statistics/sample/date@2"":""2012-7-10"",
""statistics/sample/duration@2"":""10.0""
```

}";

```
//These are the only 4 lines you'll require on your code
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
StatsConverter sc = new StatsConverter();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new StatsConverter() });
Statistics stats = serializer.Deserialize<Statistics>(json);
```

`stats` object above will deserialize to a `Statistics` object with 3 `Sample` objects in its `Samples` collection.

Comment: I just found a problem with this method: the order of `IDictionary.Keys` is unspecified, which would screw up the parsing method. Any ideas on how to overcome that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a ORM (e.g. EntityFramework) then you are just working against a datamodel so assuming you would then have a model class defined something like...

```
public class Sample
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public double Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could do something like this...

```
List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
Dictionary<string, object> data = ser.DeserializeObject(json) as Dictionary<string, object>;
var keys =  data.Keys.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i <keys.Count; i++)
{
    string k = keys[i];
    if (Regex.IsMatch(k, "^statistics/sample(@\\d*)?$"))
    {
        samples.Add(new Sample
        {
            Date = (string)data[keys[i + 1]],
            Duration = double.Parse((string)data[keys[i + 2]])
        });
    }
}
```

I just populate a list for the example and again if you are using something like EntityFramework then you could could just be adding the instances directly to your repository/datacontext.